# How to configure SSL from ACM to subdomains?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-application-load-balancer, amazon-certificate-manager

I have and EC2 set up to server both Backend and front end
using nginx
frontend.domain.org
backend.domain.org

this is my nginx config file

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name backend.domian.org;

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ubuntu/Backend/app.sock;
    }

    location /static/ {
        alias /home/ubuntu/Backend/static/;
    }

    location /media/ {
        alias /home/ubuntu/Backend/media/;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443;
    server_name backend.domain.org;


    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ubuntu/Backend/app.sock;
    }

    location /static/ {
        alias /home/ubuntu/Backend/static/;
    }

    location /media/ {
        alias /home/ubuntu/Backend/media/;
    }
}
```

now i created a load balancer and then a target group and added record in Route 53 to direct to load balancer
but my target group is giving unhealthy what should i put after this / currently i set it to /

I tried changing / URLs but i didn't work also when i access it though load balancer DNS it gives 504error

Comment: You didn't show target group setup. On what port are you sending the traffic to the instance? For healthcheck, you said it's set to /. What is returned when you go to root? In a lot of cases I've seen root path not being defined in the backend, so normally it wouldn't return HTTP 200. Best practice is to define a path like /ping or /health or similar and use it for target group healthcheck